# Cannot auth users in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a problem with my code in django. I can't login user, I have form, display users but if i write password is ignored, there is any authentication and when i click submit button i go to next site with any authentication. And when entering a password user or not does not matter as if the password was not checked. I only see in comment in html all list users and their password from db when I do examine the login page.

---

Please look at my code.

login.html

```
        {{context.error}}
{%else%}
 <form action="../logistics/choosework/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
       <select list="employees" id="opr_login" name="opr_login">
                  <option hidden="">Login</option>
                  {% for login in peoples %}
                    <option value="{{login.opr_login}}">{{ login.opr_name }} {{ login.opr_surname }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
       </select>
      <br>
      <input placeholder="Password" value="{{login.opr_pass}}" type="password" id="opr_pass" name="opr_pass">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="login" />
  </form>
{% endif %}
<hr>
```

dbmodel_index.py

```
class Peoples(models.Model):
    opr_login = models.CharField(db_column='OPR_LOGIN', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    opr_name = models.CharField(db_column='OPR_NAME', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    opr_surname = models.CharField(db_column='OPR_SURNAME', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    opr_pass = models.CharField(db_column='OPR_PASS', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PEOPLES'
```

views.py

```
    peoples = dbmodel_index.Peoples.objects.all()
    context={}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        opr_login = request.POST['opr_login']
        opr_pass = request.POST['opr_pass']
        user = authenticate(request, opr_login=opr_login, opr_pass = opr_pass)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reversed('login.html'))
        else:
            context["error"] = "Wrong password!"
            return render(request, "../logistics/choosework/", context={'peoples' : peoples})
    else:
        return render(request,'login.html', context={'peoples' : peoples})
    return render(request,'login.html', context={'peoples' : peoples})
```

Comment: Assuming `authenticate` is from `django.contrib.auth`, do you have a custom authentication backend that's able to handle your custom `Peoples` model that has a nonstandard `opr_login`/`opr_pass` field?

Comment: I have a ```from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from . import dbmodel_indeksy
from .dbmodel_index import Peoples
from django.template import loader
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.template import RequestContext``` What custom authentication facilities do you mean?

Comment: For `authenticate` to actually authenticate against that `Peoples` model of yours, you will need a custom authentication backend. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends

Comment: I recommend adding a `OneToOne` field from the `Peoples` model to `User`. Use the regular auth, and then just grab the `Peoples` object from the `User`. That's my preferred way to "extend" the `User` model.

Comment: @SamCreamer or AKX could you show me how can i do this? I am new in django and i don't know many in this framework.

Comment: This is a great tutorial for this pattern: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone